# Copy rows from slice to another dataframe where index matches

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have an array like this:

```
[487, 410, 358, 242, 180, 100, 190, 192, 180, 200,355,460]
```

These 12 points are meant to represent the cumulative sales of product for each month. So, 487 products were sold in Jan, 410 in Feb, and so on.

I'm trying to make a dataframe that will resample this to hourly data (for a year), in the 8am-4pm time window on the working days (holidays may be disregarded) So, the dataframe has all the hours, but outside 8am-4pm the value is 0. The sum of all the datapoints in the dataframe for 1 month should be as in the array above.

```
hour = df.index.hour
selector = ((8 <= hour) & (hour <= 16))
data = df[selector]
sliceddata = data[data.index.dayofweek < 5]
```

Using this in sliceddata I have all rows that are in the 8am-4pm interval. I am able to further slice the data per month by

```
temp = sliceddata[sliceddata.index.month == i] #where i=1 to 12
```

And I'm able to perform my initial desired calculations.

How can I copy the values from temp to sliceddata, and then finally back to the original dataframe?

Comment: You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: I don't really know how to begin with this one, so any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.update(temp[column_name].rename(column_name))
```

Comment: While this might be an answer to this question, it is encouraged to add an explanation to your code. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) You can also [accept your answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).